# jrew.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close

Tags: java

I'm going to the web front end of an Oracle Applications 10.7 website which requires that I install JInitiator 1.1.7.32.  Upon reaching the end of the installation for JInitiator, I get a Microsoft error stating that "jrew.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close".  The installation never completes successfully and IE is closed immediately after.  Has anyone encountered this error or know how to fix it?

I've tried updating the JInitiator to a newer version and updating the JRE on the machine but neither seem to have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the fix for the JInitiator problem for version 1.1.7.32.  Here it is:

1. Close all Internet Explorer windows
2. Open My Computer and go to this path on the local machine:

   C:\Program Files\Oracle\JInitiator 1.1.7.32\bin
3. In that directory, search for a file named symcjit.dll and rename it to symcjit.old
4. Open Internet Explorer and retest the Oracle Apps

Answer (score 0):

You should try the replacement `jvm.dll` file which can be obtained [from here](http://sathyabh.at/2009/06/27/fixing-internet-explorer-crash-on-launching-oracle-forms-application-with-jinitiator/), it seems to have worked for lots of folks.

Comment: I'm getting this error when attempting to install the JInitiator package so I don't even get as far as having the installation files load successfully.

Comment: After clicking 'Don't Send' about 50 times, it installs.  When going back out to the website in IE, the browser crashes without any error messages.

Comment: The JVM.DLL file doesn't exist after forcing it to install.